# Set Vite base via GitLab CI_PAGES_URL variable

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, vite

[Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#gitlab-pages-and-gitlab-ci) describe how to set the correct `base` inside `vite.config.js` when deploying a static site to GitLab Pages.

Is it possible to configure `base` dynamically inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of altering `vite.config.js`, it is possible to pass `--base` to `vite build`. To get the correct path on GitLab CI, use the predefined `CI_PAGES_URL` variable:

Example `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
...
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - yarn run build --base=$CI_PAGES_URL
    - cp -a dist/. public/
...
```